# accented characters not copied correctly from Access to SAP intermittently

Tags: ms-access, sap-erp

I have an application in access that generates a text file which is then copied to the description section of SAP. I also store the text in the database for future manipulation! 99% of the time this works great except occasionally instead of the accented characters getting copied I get &#233 instead of é .The text is still ok in the database. If they re-copy it again , it`s ok! (The recopy might be a few days later after someone sees the error) All text in Access is good.
I think it may be due to an application the was run before doing the access application that screws up the UTF-8 coding.
Their computers and Access are in French Canada. Computers are windows10 build 1909 , SAP 750

And thoughts guys

Comment: Maybe this info will be helpful https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/2088050

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with character coding. I just have to figure out why its works fine 99% of the time, then bugs up for no apparent reason. I'm guessing some function in SAP can change the format, that the user performs prior to executing the copy function.